# What are the factors in voting someone into the Baseball Hall of Fame?

Tags: baseball, statistics, hall-of-fame

What are the determinant factors in voting someone into the Hall of Fame in baseball? Or any sport for that matter. Is it just statistics or is it more of what that player represented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imo I would say its a combination of the two. For instance Mark McGwire put up alot of good numbers (plenty good enough to get into the hall) but he admitted to using steroids and has yet to be voted in because of it.

So you do have to have good statistics but you also have to play the game the right way with integrity and sportsmanship.

It will be interesting to see how the voters vote now that we got more steroid users coming up on the Hall Ballot like Sammy Sosa, Roger Clemons, and Barry Bonds

Comment: So true. It's real unfortunate to see all the players with great stats get passed by because of substance abuse.

Comment: @chris maybe but I dont necessarily want cheaters to make the hall either